# Base SAS - Proc SQL

Tags: sas

**Need BASE SAS - PROC SQL Code** . I have a table with following data

```
ID Contact          Preference_ID
1  1111111111       Preference1
1  Test1@test.com   Preference2
1  3333333333       Preference4
2  4444444444       Preference1
2  Test5@test.com   Preference5
```

Here I have ID, Mobile, Email and Preference_ID columns. Preference_ID column can take values from Preference1 to Preference5

I want to write a **Base SAS - Proc SQL Query** which can give me data in the following format

```
ID Preference1 Preference2    Preference3 Preference4 Preference5
1  1111111111  test@test.com              3333333333
2  4444444444                                        Test5@test.com
```

Means Preference_ID row should become column of the output data and contact details should be filled row wise according to the ID.

Comment: Why SQL?  Why not just use PROC TRANSPOSE since that is what it is designed to do?

Comment: SAS SQL doesn't support PIVOT which other flavours of SQL use and would allow this to happen more easily in SQL. So the best approach would be to use the PROC that supports it, PROC TRANSPOSE.

Comment: So what have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

use proc tranpose as @Tom Suggests it is easy. Proc SQL will involve lot of hard coding.

```
data have;
 input ID Contact:$20.       Preference_ID:$11.;
datalines;
1  1111111111       Preference1
1  Test1@test.com   Preference2
1  3333333333       Preference4
2  4444444444       Preference1
2  Test5@test.com   Preference5
;



proc transpose data = have out=want(drop=_name_);
by id; id preference_id;
var contact;
run;



 proc sql;
 create table want as 
 select id,
   max(case when Preference_ID="Preference1" then contact end) as Preference1,
   max(case when Preference_ID="Preference2" then contact end) as Preference2,
   max(case when Preference_ID="Preference3" then contact end) as Preference3,
   max(case when Preference_ID="Preference4" then contact end) as Preference4,
   max(case when Preference_ID="Preference5" then contact end) as Preference5
from have
group by id
 ;
```